# Django rest how to show hierarchical data in api response

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am getting the category id for GET request but I want to show text in hierarchical structure like child1 -> child -> child3

my expected response will be look like this

```
{
'category': 'child1 -> child -> child3'
}
```

now getting response like this

```
{
'category': 1
}
```

somethings look like that my model where it show category name on hierarchical order
[image]

my category_model

```
class Product_category(models.Model):
      domain = models.CharField(max_length=250)
      parent_category = models.ForeignKey('self',on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True)
      category_name = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True,)
      category_icon = models.ImageField(upload_to=dynamic_icon_upload_path,blank=True,null=True)

      def get_hierarchical_name(self):
        if self.parent_category:
            return f"{self.parent_category.get_hierarchical_name()}->{self.category_name}"
        else:
            return f"{self.category_name}"
      
     

      def __str__(self):
        return self.get_hierarchical_name()
```

my product model

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True,null=True)
    category  = models.ForeignKey(Product_category,blank=True,null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

my serilizer

```
class ParentProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
       class Meta:
        model = Product
         fields = ['category',...others product fields]
```

see the screenshot where right now I am getting id instated for hierarchical  text
[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way to provide custom output in a serializer is using a SerializerMethodField. If you want to override the way the `category` field is represented, define a `category` attribute on the serializer that is a SerializerMethodField. Then define a method on the serializer called `get_category`. This method will be called by the serializer to supply the value of the SerializerMethodField. You can have this method return the string representation of the product's category.

```py
class ParentProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['category',...others product fields]

    def get_category(self, instance):
        return str(instance.category)
```

The [Django REST Framework documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) has more info on SerializerMethodField and other useful serializer fields.